# Navigate to another page on rowselect of datatable in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

I have a primefaces datatable where number of records are displaying.

`I want navigate to another page on the rowSelect event (to edit the selected entity for example)`.

The closest sample/demo I could find was use the p:ajax tag to bind the rowSelect event to a listener method 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf

I also got one article for the same  http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14664

, I tried to implement in same as they did.But it also didn't worked.

I am trying in this way and guide me If I missed anything.

> ```
>    <p:dataTable var="product" value="#{addPatientBB.patientAddList}" paginator="true" rows="10" 
>              selection="#{addPatientBB.pat}" selectionMode="single"> 
>
>     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{addPatientBB.onRowSelect}" />  
>
>
>
>         <p:column>  
>             <f:facet name="header">  
>                 <h:outputText value="FirstName" />  
>             </f:facet>  
>             <h:outputText value="#{product.firstName}" />  
>         </p:column>  
>
>           <p:column>  
>
>             <f:facet name="header">  
>                 <h:outputText value="Email" />  
>             </f:facet>  
>           <h:outputText value="#{product.email}" />    
>
>            </p:column>  
>
>
>         <p:column>  
>             <f:facet name="header">  
>                 <h:outputText value="Gender" />  
>             </f:facet>  
>           <h:outputText value="#{product.gender}" />    
>
>            </p:column> 
>
>      </p:dataTable>
> ```

And Backing bean is :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddPatientBB implements Serializable
{
    private Patient pat;

    public Patient getPat()
    {
    System.out.println("tried to get pat");
    return pat;
    }

    public void setPat(Patient pat)
    {
    this.pat = pat;
    System.out.println("tried to set pat");
    }

    public void onRowSelect()
    {
    System.out.println("inside onRow select  Method");
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    System.out.println("navigation objt created");

    configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("Page?faces-redirect=true");

    // Page is my navigation page where I wish to navigate named as
    // "Page.xhtml"

    System.out.println("Navigation executed");

    }

}
```

So how can I navigate to another page on rowselect event? and how can display its values after navigationg the form.

I am able to go inside onRowSelect() method , actually problem is he is not able to get or understood that path :

> configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("Page?faces-redirect=true");

so he is not able to print any logs after this line.
why is it so? is it because of I am using Liferay?

Pla guide me.

Comment: what happens with your code? is onRowSelect() method executed? is the selected Patient set in the bean?

Comment: no, not even patient selected in the bean, nor onrowselect method is executed

Comment: is the dataTable surronded by h:form?

Comment: yes, it is surrounded by h:form, i tried by removing it also, but still not getting any logs, why?

Comment: it has to be surrounded by h:form, so don't remove them. try adding the rowKey attribute to the datable: rowKey="{product.id}" (replace id for the actual id attribute of the class).

Comment: I added my patId to as a rowkey , but still not even able to get inside patient object method (selection="#{addPatientBB.pt}")???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11646/discussion-between-damian-and-pravingate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well i think the onRowSelect is never executed because you defined it wrong.

Try this:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)
{


  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("page.xhtml?id=" +pat.getId());


}
```

Comment: According to the JSF specs, you have to call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); after redirection.

Comment: I don't understand why you eddited my answer with faulty information. From de jsf docs clearly says: Redirect a request to the specified URL, and cause the responseComplete() method to be called on the FacesContext instance for the current request.

Comment: Look at https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344 final release spec and look at chapter 2.1.3, on the beggining of page 2-4 it clearly says that "It is then necessary to tell the JSF implementation that the response has already been
created, so that the Render Response phase of the request processing lifecycle should be skipped. This is accomplished
by calling the responseComplete() method on the FacesContext instance for the current request, prior to
returning from event handlers or application actions."

Comment: You're right but the redirect method self calls responseComplete() so no need to do it yourself. See https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect(java.lang.String)

Comment: That docs is just for Mojarra RI, however other implementations could vary.

Answer (score -3):

If u are using FacesServlet then use.jsf instead of .xhtml

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)
{
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("page.jsf?id="+pat.getId());
}
```